# Trying to set up an SVN server on Ubuntu 14.04 but can't check out an svn

Tags: svn, ubuntu, apache2

I've installed `subversion` and `libapache2-svn` on Ubuntu Server 14.04. I can check out an svn locally without any problems so I know Subversion is working.

I'm attempting to check it out using TortoiseSVN on a Windows Machine but when I do I get the following list of errors:

*Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://myurl.com/svn/testproject'*

Unexpected HTTP status 500 'Internal Server Error' on '/svn/testproject'

Additional Errors:

OPTIONS request on '/svn/testproject' failed: 500 Internal Server Error

In `testproject`, my `passwd` file is as follows:

```
[users]
username1 = password1
```

and my `authz` file is as follows

```
[groups]
username1_group = username1

[/svn/testproject]
@username1_group = rw
```

and `/etc/apache2/mods-enables/dav_svn.conf` is as follows:

```
<Location /svn/testproject>
     DAV svn
     SVNPath /svn/testproject
     AuthType Basic
     AuthName "myproject subversion repository"
     AuthUserFile /svn/tesproject/conf/passwd
     Require valid-user
</Location>
```

My understaing of it is that this should be enough for me to check out my svn at the following url above. TortiseSVN is prompting me to enter a username and password but the the combination in my `passwd` file doesn't work. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `sudo chown -R :www-data rootoftherepositories` This may fix the issue. Is it resolving from tortoise svn, with IP address instead of domain?

Comment: changing the group didn't work, nor did using the IP instead of the domain

Comment: ls -l gives: drwxrwxr-x   3 www-data www-data  4096 Aug  1 06:34 svn

Answer (score 1):

I see a lot of errors and mistakes and misinterpretaions

- If your repository served by Apache (not svnserve), plain-text passwd-file **will not work**: you have to [build password-file](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.authn.basic) with `htpasswd`
- You **must not** use intersected Location and SVNPath|SVNParentPath (it will be infinitive loop or redirects in result)
- `authz`-file have not any sense in your config, because you haven't enabled [Path-Based Authorization](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html) with AuthzSVNAccessFile

> Subversion offers path-based access control in Apache via the
>   mod_authz_svn module, which must be loaded using the LoadModule
>   directive in httpd.conf in the same fashion that mod_dav_svn itself is
>   loaded. To enable the use of this module for your repositories, you'll
>   add the AuthzSVNAccessFile directive

- `[/svn/testproject]` is authz-file also is **totally incorrect** definition, because it defines path `/svn/testproject` *inside your single repository*, not root of repository, as you expect.

Quote from [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html)

> If you're using the SVNParentPath directive, it's important to specify
>   the repository names in your sections. If you omit them, a section
>   such as [/some/dir] will match the path /some/dir in every repository.
>   If you're using the SVNPath directive, however, it's fine to provide
>   only paths in your sections—after all, there's only one repository.

A **Must Fixes** for restoring minimal functionality are pp.1-2

Answer (score 0):

Change

[groups]

username1_group = username1

to

[groups]

username1_group = **passwd**

Comment: Please explain your answer for better understanding to the SO Users.

Comment: change username1_group = username1 to username1_group = passwd